# TPM clear on Bios not reset all accounts using PIN numbers

Tags: windows, windows-11, tpm

I have an interesting problem: Windows 11 Pro on 3 year old  computer with TPM 2.0. Windows is updated to latest version, eset internet security , 3 user accounts, one local with admin rights, two Microsoft accounts with pin login using TPM. When I cleared TPM in BIOS and then tried to login to Windows, one user with pin had to login with their Microsoft account and set a new pin. The  second user with a Microsoft account could still login with their old pin.  That is strange becouse TPM was cleared. What could be wrong?

Comment: Provide the BitLocker protector information for the system

Comment: Bitlocker Protection is off. I reproduce issue with clean Windows install using Outlook account wich TPM dosn't work. After install all programs I have same issue. Windows security dosn't see any problems with core isolation, ets...

Comment: But I use win on to go. But this irrelewant besouse tpm is not supported on win on  to go. I read article published 23.3.2023 on MS site

Answer (score 0):

I think I foud issue but I am not 100% sure. Two years from now. I test hw security key, which it's software drivers replace or add in local authorization security service. After that the user change his PIN login number. This user doesn't need to change PIN after TPM clear. Other users does. Also windows security shows that additional LSA protection does not work propertly. I try enable Local Security Authority (LSA) Protection in Windows 11 but no succes so I do clean install.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).